# How do I upgrade to the newest version of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running on OSX Snow Leopard.  Using `ruby -v` I see I have 1.8.7 and using `rails -v` I have 2.3.5

When I try gem update rails I get the following error:

> bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help to upgrade my rails version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244151/need-help-to-upgrade-my-rails-version)

Comment: He's upgrading an application, I just need to update the version of rails installed.  Also he's on a Windows machine, and I'm on a mac.  In addition that thread is a year old and has items specific to that version which are now out dated.

Comment: See my answer (below)

Comment: A question: why was this question migrated from stackoverflow to superuser? It's clearly about software development (and the related things that go with it, such as how to configure X dev environment).

Comment: @Zabba: probably they confused SuperUser and ServerFault; this is not software development questions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) instead of trying to mess with ruby that comes default with Mac os

Answer (score 2):

The error message you're receiving is because the new version of Rails requires a newer version of `gem` than you have. You can update `gem` like this:

```
gem update --system
```

You may need `sudo` if you're using system gem. You can check the version of gem by running:

```
gem -v
```

Once this is done, and you can confirm your gem version is at least 1.3.6, you should be able to run:

```
gem update rails
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have Brew or Macport:

If you have Brew installled then you use the following command to install:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

or

```
brew gem install rails
```

Please go through this link:

> http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 0):

From my comment, you can upgrade `rails` by this command (I hope):

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: When I try install rails or update rails I get the following error:

bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

Comment: Run dis: `sudo gem update -V`

Comment: I ran that and it seemed to work, but I still get the above error